# How to combine slider range and some values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I have multiple slider, and some values. I want to combine it, but still something wrong.

- **First**, I have a number ***(could be change at any time)***, it means end element of an array, which started from 0 (Example: 4 means [0,1,2,3,4])
- **Second**, I have some slider ***(numbers of slider could be change at any time)***, and want that array can split evenly and match the slider's ranger value for every slider
  I have still problem when 2nd slider at [42,50]
  Can someone help me fix it?

```js
 $(document).on("ready", function() {
  var number = $("input[name='number']").val();
  initSlider($(".slider-container"), number);
 });
 $(document).on("blur", "input[name='number']", function() {
  var number = $(this).val();
  initSlider($(".slider-container"), number);
 });
 $(document).on("click", ".add-more", function() {
  var number = $("input[name='number']").val();
  var html   = '<div class="slider-item"><div class="result">Result: <span class="value">2</span></div><div class="slider-range"></div></div>';
  $(".slider-list").append(html);
  initSlider($(".slider-container"), number);
 });
function parseNumber(number) {
 var response = [];
 for(var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
  response.push(i);
 }
 return response;
}
function initRange(prev_values, current_values, next_values, number, remain_number) {
 number            = parseInt(number);
 var return_values = [0, 0];
 var arrange       = (100 / (number + 1));
 if($.isArray(current_values)) {
  if(prev_values[0] > 1) {
   if($.isArray(prev_values)) {
    prev_values    = [Math.round(prev_values[0]), Math.round(prev_values[1])];
    next_values    = [Math.round(next_values[0]), Math.round(next_values[1])];
    current_values = [Math.round(current_values[0]), Math.round(current_values[1])];
    return_values[0] = Math.round(current_values[0] / arrange);
    return_values[1] = Math.round(next_values[0] / arrange) - 1;
    console.log(prev_values);
   }
  }
  else {
   prev_values = [Math.round(prev_values[0]), Math.round(prev_values[1])];
   next_values = [Math.round(next_values[0]), Math.round(next_values[1])];
   if(Math.round((prev_values[1] + 1) / arrange) > 0) {
    return_values[0] = Math.floor((prev_values[1] - 1) / arrange) + 1;
   } else {
    return_values[0] = 0;
   }
   return_values[1] = Math.round(next_values[0] / arrange) - 1;
  }
 }
 else {
  current_values = Math.round(current_values);
  if(prev_values == 1) {
   prev_values      = Math.round(prev_values);
   next_values      = [Math.round(next_values[0]), Math.round(next_values[1])];
   return_values[0] = 0;
   return_values[1] = Math.floor((current_values - 1) / arrange);
   if(return_values[1] == Math.round(next_values[0] / arrange) && !$.isArray(next_values)) {
    return_values[1] -= 1;
   }
   if($.isArray(next_values) && Math.round((current_values + 1) / arrange) == 0) {
    return_values[1] = -1;
   }
  }
  else {
   next_values      = Math.round(next_values);
   prev_values      = [Math.round(prev_values[0]), Math.round(prev_values[1])];
   return_values[0] = Math.round(current_values / arrange);
   return_values[1] = Math.round((100 - current_values) / arrange) > 0 ? number : ((number - current_values) > 0 ? (number - current_values) : 0);
  }
 }
 if((return_values[0] == 'NA') || (return_values[1] == 'NA') || (return_values[0] > return_values[1])) {
  return_values = ['NA', 'NA'];
 }
 return return_values;
}
function initSlider(selector, number) {
 var slider_list   = selector.find(".slider-list .slider-item");
 var slider_count  = slider_list.size();
 var slider_values = [1, 100 / slider_count];
 var parse_number  = parseNumber(number);
 var slides        = [];
 var ranger_values;
 var prev_values;
 var next_values;
 var count         = 0;
 $.each(slider_list, function() {
  var th        = $(this).find(".slider-range");
  slides[count] = th[0];
  if(th.hasClass("noUi-target")) {
   slides[count].noUiSlider.destroy();
  }
  if($(this).is(":first-child")) {
   noUiSlider.create(slides[count], {
    start   : slider_values[1],
    connect : "lower",
    tooltips: true,
    range   : {
     min: 1,
     max: 100
    },
    format  : wNumb({
     decimals: 0
    })
   });
   th.addClass("first");
   ranger_values = initRange(1, slider_values[1], [(slider_values[1] + 1), slider_values[1] + (slider_values[1] - slider_values[0] + 1)], number, 0);
   th.parent().find(".result .value").html(ranger_values.join("-"));
   th.attr('data-from',ranger_values[0]).attr('data-to',ranger_values[1]);
   slides[count].noUiSlider.on("change", function(values, handle) {
    changeSlider(th, slides[count], values[handle]);
   });
   slides[count].noUiSlider.on("update", function(values, handle) {

    ranger_values = initRange(1, parseInt(values[handle]), [(parseInt(values[handle]) + 1), parseInt(values[handle]) + (parseInt(values[handle]) - slider_values[0] + 1)], number, parse_number);
    th.parent().find(".result .value").html(ranger_values.join("-"));
    th.attr('data-from',ranger_values[0]).attr('data-to',ranger_values[1]);
   });
  } else if($(this).is(":last-child")) {
   noUiSlider.create(slides[count], {
    start   : slider_values[0],
    connect : "upper",
    tooltips: true,
    range   : {
     min: 1,
     max: 100
    },
    format  : wNumb({
     decimals: 0
    })
   });
   th.removeClass("middle").addClass("last");
   ranger_values = initRange([slider_values[0] - (slider_values[1] - slider_values[0]) - 1, (slider_values[0] - 1)], slider_values[0], 100, number, 0);
   th.parent().find(".result .value").html(ranger_values.join("-"));
   th.attr('data-from',ranger_values[0]).attr('data-to',ranger_values[1]);
   slides[count].noUiSlider.on("change", function(values, handle) {
    changeSlider(th, slides[count], values[handle]);
   });
   slides[count].noUiSlider.on("update", function(values, handle) {
    ranger_values = initRange([values[handle] - (slider_values[1] - values[handle]) - 1, (values[handle] - 1)], values[handle], 100, number);
    th.parent().find(".result .value").html(ranger_values.join("-"));
    th.attr('data-from',ranger_values[0]).attr('data-to',ranger_values[1]);
   });
  } else {
   noUiSlider.create(slides[count], {
    start   : slider_values,
    connect : true,
    tooltips: true,
    range   : {
     min: 1,
     max: 100
    },
    format  : wNumb({
     decimals: 0
    })
   });
   th.removeClass("last").addClass("middle");
   prev_values   = [slider_values[0] - (slider_values[1] - slider_values[0]) - 1, (slider_values[0] - 1)];
   next_values   = [(slider_values[1] + 1), slider_values[1] + (slider_values[1] - slider_values[0] + 1)];
   ranger_values = initRange(prev_values, slider_values, next_values, number, 0);
   th.parent().find(".result .value").html(ranger_values.join("-"));
   th.attr('data-from',ranger_values[0]).attr('data-to',ranger_values[1]);
   slides[count].noUiSlider.on("change", function(values) {
    changeSlider(th, slides[count], values);
   });
   slides[count].noUiSlider.on("update", function(values) {
    values = [parseInt(values[0]), parseInt(values[1])];
    if(count <= 2) {
     prev_values = [0, (values[0] - 1)];
    } else {
     prev_values = [values[0] - (values[1] - values[0]) - count * 2, (values[0] - 1)];
    }
    next_values = [(values[1] + 1), values[1] + (values[1] - values[0] + 1)];
    ranger_values = initRange(prev_values, values, next_values, number);
    th.parent().find(".result .value").html(ranger_values.join("-"));
    th.attr('data-from',ranger_values[0]).attr('data-to',ranger_values[1]);
   });
  }
  slider_values = [(slider_values[1] + 1), slider_values[1] + (slider_values[1] - slider_values[0]) + 1];
  count++;
 });
}
function changeSlider(object, slide, values) {
 var old_values;
 var next_slide = object.parent().next().find(".slider-range");
 var prev_slide = object.parent().prev().find(".slider-range");
 if($.isArray(values)) {
  values = [parseInt(values[0]), parseInt(values[1])];
 } else {
  values = parseInt(values);
 }
 if(next_slide.hasClass("noUi-target")) {
  var current_next_values = next_slide[0].noUiSlider.get();
  if($.isArray(current_next_values) && current_next_values.length == 2) {
   current_next_values = [parseInt(current_next_values[0]), parseInt(current_next_values[1])];
   if($.isArray(values)) {
    if(values[1] > current_next_values[1]) {
     old_values    = values;
     old_values[1] = current_next_values[1] - 1;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(old_values);
    }
    current_next_values[0] = values[1] + 1;
   } else {
    if(values >= current_next_values[1]) {
     old_values = current_next_values[1] - 1;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(old_values);
    }
    current_next_values[0] = values + 1;
   }
  } else {
   current_next_values = parseInt(current_next_values);
   if($.isArray(values)) {
    current_next_values = values[1] + 1;
   } else {
    current_next_values = values + 1;
   }
  }
  next_slide[0].noUiSlider.set(current_next_values);
 }
 if(prev_slide.hasClass("noUi-target")) {
  var current_prev_values = prev_slide[0].noUiSlider.get();
  if($.isArray(current_prev_values) && current_prev_values.length == 2) {
   current_prev_values = [parseInt(current_prev_values[0]), parseInt(current_prev_values[1])];
   if($.isArray(values)) {
    if(values[0] < current_prev_values[0]) {
     old_values    = values;
     old_values[0] = current_prev_values[0] + 1;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(old_values);
    }
    current_prev_values[1] = values[0] - 1;
   } else {
    if(values <= current_prev_values[0]) {
     old_values = current_prev_values[0] + 1;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(old_values);
    }
    current_prev_values[1] = values - 1;
   }
  } else {
   current_prev_values = parseInt(current_prev_values);
   if($.isArray(values)) {
    current_prev_values = values[0] - 1;
   } else {
    current_prev_values = values - 1;
   }
  }
  prev_slide[0].noUiSlider.set(current_prev_values);
 }
}
```

```css
  .slider-container {
   width: 500px;
   margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .slider-item {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .result span {
   font-weight: bold;
  }

  .noUi-handle-lower .noUi-tooltip {
   top: 28px !important;
   bottom: -32px !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="http://refreshless.com/noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://refreshless.com/noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://refreshless.com/nouislider/documentation/assets/wNumb.js"></script>
<div style="top:40px;left:40px;position: absolute;">
 Number: <input title="" type="number" min="2" name="number" value="4"><br>
 Array: <span class="array">[0,1,2,3,4]</span>
 <br>

 <div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-list">
   <div class="slider-item">
    <div class="result">Result: <span class="value">2</span></div>
    <div class="slider-range"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider-item">
    <div class="result">Result: <span class="value">2</span></div>
    <div class="slider-range"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider-item">
    <div class="result">Result: <span class="value">2</span></div>
    <div class="slider-range"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider-item">
    <div class="result">Result: <span class="value">2</span></div>
    <div class="slider-range"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <button type="button" class="add-more">Add More slide</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I resolved myself by re init after slide event.

```js
 $(document).on("ready", function() {
  var number = $("input[name='number']").val();
  initSlider($(".slider-container"), number);
 });
 $(document).on("blur", "input[name='number']", function() {
  var number = $(this).val();
  var list   = [];
  for(var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
   list.push(i);
  }
  $(this).parent().find("span.array").html('[' + list.join(',') + ']');
  initSlider($(".slider-container"), number);
 });
 $(document).on("click", ".add-more", function() {
  var number = $("input[name='number']").val();
  var count  = $(".slider-item").size();
  var html   = '<div class="slider-item"><div class="result">Range: <span class="value">2</span></div><div class="slider-range" data-id="' + count + '"></div></div>';
  $(".slider-list").append(html);
  initSlider($(".slider-container"), number);
 });
function spliceNumber(numbers, range_value) {
 for(var i = numbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  for(var j = range_value.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
   if(numbers[i] == range_value[j]) {
    numbers.splice(i, 1);
   }
  }
 }
 return numbers;
}
function roundNumber(values, remain_number) {
 var ranger   = [];
 var response = [];
 values       = [Math.floor(values[0]), Math.floor(values[1])];
 for(var i = 0; i < remain_number.length; i++) {
  for(var j = values[0]; j <= values[1]; j++) {
   if(j == remain_number[i]) {
    ranger.push(j);
   }
  }
 }
 switch(ranger.length) {
  case 0:
   response.push('NA');
   break;
  case 1:
   response = ranger;
   break;
  default:
   response[0] = ranger[0];
   response[1] = ranger[ranger.length - 1];
   break;
 }
 return response;
}
function initSlider(selector, number, ranger_list) {
 number            = parseFloat(number);
 var slider_list   = selector.find(".slider-list .slider-item");
 var slider_count  = slider_list.size();
 var step          = (number) / 100;
 var slider_values = [0, (number) / slider_count];
 var numbers       = [];
 var rangers       = [];
 if(!$.isArray(ranger_list) || ranger_list.length == 0) {
  ranger_list = [];
 }
 for(var i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
  numbers.push(i);
 }
 $.each(slider_list, function() {
  var th    = $(this).find(".slider-range");
  var id    = parseInt(th.attr('data-id'));
  var slide = th[0];
  var start;
  if(th.hasClass("noUi-target")) {
   slide.noUiSlider.destroy();
  }
  if($(this).is(":first-child")) {
   start = ranger_list[id] || slider_values[1];
   if(ranger_list[id] == 0) {
    start = 0;
   }
   noUiSlider.create(slide, {
    start   : start,
    step    : step,
    connect : "lower",
    tooltips: true,
    range   : {
     min: 0,
     max: number
    }
   });
   rangers = roundNumber([0, slide.noUiSlider.get()], numbers);
   numbers = spliceNumber(numbers, rangers);
   th.addClass("first");
   th.parent().find(".result .value").html(rangers.join("-"));
   th.attr('data-from', rangers[0]).attr('data-to', rangers[1]);
   slide.noUiSlider.on("update", function(values, handle) {
    th.find('.noUi-tooltip').html(Math.round(values[handle] / step));
    ranger_list[id] = parseFloat(values[handle]);
   });
   slide.noUiSlider.on("change", function(values, handle) {
    changeSlider(th, slide, values[handle], step);
    initSlider(selector, number, ranger_list);
   });
  } else if($(this).is(":last-child")) {
   start = ranger_list[id] || slider_values[0];
   noUiSlider.create(slide, {
    start   : start,
    step    : step,
    connect : "upper",
    tooltips: true,
    range   : {
     min: 0,
     max: number
    }
   });
   rangers = roundNumber([slide.noUiSlider.get(), number], numbers);
   numbers = spliceNumber(numbers, rangers);
   th.removeClass("middle").addClass("last");
   th.parent().find(".result .value").html(rangers.join("-"));
   th.attr('data-from', rangers[0]).attr('data-to', rangers[1]);
   slide.noUiSlider.on("update", function(values, handle) {
    th.find('.noUi-tooltip').html(Math.round(values[handle] / step));
    ranger_list[id] = parseFloat(values[handle]);
   });
   slide.noUiSlider.on("change", function(values, handle) {
    changeSlider(th, slide, values[handle], step);
    initSlider(selector, number, ranger_list);
   });
  } else {
   start = ranger_list[id] || slider_values;
   noUiSlider.create(slide, {
    start   : start,
    step    : step,
    connect : true,
    tooltips: true,
    range   : {
     min: 0,
     max: number
    }
   });
   rangers = roundNumber(slide.noUiSlider.get(), numbers);
   numbers = spliceNumber(numbers, rangers);
   th.removeClass("last").addClass("middle");
   th.parent().find(".result .value").html(rangers.join("-"));
   th.attr('data-from', rangers[0]).attr('data-to', rangers[1]);
   slide.noUiSlider.on("update", function(values) {
    th.find('.noUi-tooltip:first').html(Math.round(values[0] / step));
    th.find('.noUi-tooltip:last').html(Math.round(values[1] / step));
    ranger_list[id] = [parseFloat(values[0]), parseFloat(values[1])];
   });
   slide.noUiSlider.on("change", function(values) {
    changeSlider(th, slide, values, step);
    initSlider(selector, number, ranger_list);
   });
  }
  slider_values = [(slider_values[1] + step), slider_values[1] + (slider_values[1] - slider_values[0]) + step];
 });
}
function changeSlider(object, slide, values, step) {
 var old_values;
 var next_slide = object.parent().next().find(".slider-range");
 var prev_slide = object.parent().prev().find(".slider-range");
 if($.isArray(values)) {
  values = [parseFloat(values[0]), parseFloat(values[1])];
 } else {
  values = parseFloat(values);
 }
 if(next_slide.hasClass("noUi-target")) {
  var current_next_values = next_slide[0].noUiSlider.get();
  if($.isArray(current_next_values) && current_next_values.length == 2) {
   current_next_values = [parseFloat(current_next_values[0]), parseFloat(current_next_values[1])];
   if($.isArray(values)) {
    if(values[1] > current_next_values[1]) {
     old_values    = values;
     old_values[1] = current_next_values[1] - step;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(old_values);
    }
    current_next_values[0] = values[1] + step;
   } else {
    if(values >= current_next_values[1]) {
     old_values = current_next_values[1] - step;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(old_values);
    }
    current_next_values[0] = values + step;
   }
  } else {
   current_next_values = parseFloat(current_next_values);
   if($.isArray(values)) {
    current_next_values = values[1] + step;
    if(values[1] == (step * 100)) {
     values[1] -= step;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(values);
    }
   } else {
    current_next_values = values + step;
    if(values == (step * 100)) {
     values -= step;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(values);
    }
   }
  }
  next_slide[0].noUiSlider.set(current_next_values);
 }
 if(prev_slide.hasClass("noUi-target")) {
  var current_prev_values = prev_slide[0].noUiSlider.get();
  if($.isArray(current_prev_values) && current_prev_values.length == 2) {
   current_prev_values = [parseFloat(current_prev_values[0]), parseFloat(current_prev_values[1])];
   if($.isArray(values)) {
    if(values[0] < current_prev_values[0]) {
     old_values    = values;
     old_values[0] = current_prev_values[0] + step;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(old_values);
    }
    current_prev_values[1] = values[0] - step;
   } else {
    if(values <= current_prev_values[0]) {
     old_values = current_prev_values[0] + step;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(old_values);
    }
    current_prev_values[1] = values - step;
   }
  } else {
   current_prev_values = parseFloat(current_prev_values);
   if($.isArray(values)) {
    current_prev_values = values[0] - step;
    if(values[0] == 0) {
     values[0] += step;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(values);
     current_prev_values = 0;
    }
   } else {
    current_prev_values = values - step;
    if(values == 0) {
     values += step;
     slide.noUiSlider.set(values);
     current_prev_values = 0;
    }
   }
  }
  prev_slide[0].noUiSlider.set(current_prev_values);
 }
}
```

```css
  .slider-container {
   width: 500px;
   margin-top: 20px;
  }

  .slider-item {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .result span {
   font-weight: bold;
  }

  .noUi-handle-lower .noUi-tooltip {
   top: 28px !important;
   bottom: -32px !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://refreshless.com/noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://refreshless.com/noUiSlider/distribute/nouislider.js"></script>
<div style="top:40px;left:40px;position: absolute;">
 Number: <input title="" type="number" min="2" name="number" value="2"><br>
 Array: <span class="array">[0,1,2]</span>
 <br>

 <div class="slider-container">
  <div class="slider-list">
   <div class="slider-item">
    <div class="result">Result: <span class="value">2</span></div>
    <div class="slider-range" data-id="0"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider-item">
    <div class="result">Result: <span class="value">2</span></div>
    <div class="slider-range" data-id="1"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <button type="button" class="add-more">Add More slide</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```